# error while doing ng-repeat over JSON object array

Tags: angularjs, json

I've got a JSON Object Array which comes directly from NodeJS as a response to angular's app.js. It contains few records which im using to display on the frontend on page load but it's not working not getting any specific error either. Any Suggestion ?

I've tried this on frontend:

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in msg.products">
<td>{{d.id}}</td>
<td>{{d.name}}</td>
<td>{{d.email}}</td>
<td>{{d.phone}}</td>
<td>{{d.blood_group}}</td>
<td ><a href="" ng-click="edit($event);" data-toggle="modal" id="{{d.id}}" data-target="#editModal">Edit</td>
<td><a href="">Delete</td>
</tr>
```

My JSON in angular:

```
{"products":[{"id":1,"name":"laptop"},{"id":2,"name":"microwave"}]}
```

Comment: I just plugged this into the SO snippet editor and it displays the two rows fine. There is something else going on that you have not shown us. Can you create a [MCVE] that demonstrates the exact issue you are experiencing?

Comment: @sid can you try to make msg = angular.toJson(msg) in your controller?

Comment: try doing something like this to ensure the object is what you are expecting it to look like: <h1 ng-bind="msg"> </h1>. a plunker example would be useful. Also, you have not shown us any controller code, please update.